# How change dataset (like pivottable in excell)

Tags: python, pandas, syntax, dataset, keyerror

I imported a csv-file to a pandas dataset (phyton)

|  | ParamID | EquipmentID | SetValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Line1 | 217.0 |
| 1 | 2 | Line1 | 3.0 |
| 2 | 4 | Line1 | 0.0 |
| 3 | 6 | Line1 | 17.0 |
| 4 | 2 | Line2 | 3.0 |
| 5 | 4 | Line2 | 0.0 |
| 6 | 6 | Line2 | 17.0 |

i would like to change this to another table where i can see the difference/Line

|  | ParamID | LINE1 | LINE2 | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1:--- | 217.0 | / | 217.0 |
| 1 | 2 | 3.0 | 3.0 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0 |
| 3 | 6 | 17.0 | 17.0 | 0 |

I tried `pivot1=pd.pivot_table(new_df, index = 'Region')` but this gives an error: "KeyError: 'Region'"

Additional question on the given solution:
If "Line1" and "Line2" where numbers (21 and 22 )in the first table why does`df1['Difference'] = (df1['21'].replace(np.nan,0) - df1['22'].replace(np.nan,0))`gives a KeyError on 21

Comment: Marvy, referring to your additional question, your KeyError on 21 one possible reason is the values of `EquipmentID` are numbers.  Then, the column labels become number instead of string.  You can try to use `df1[21]` (21 instead of '21') to see whether it works.

Comment: That was it , Tried that but probably got another error

Comment: Marvy, what error you got now ?  Maybe, you can also take a look at my solution and see whether it works for your latest situation.  Of course, similarly also use  21 instead of '21' in the column names.

Comment: @Marvy you're saying that the data is not always Line1/2 and could be something else ?  In that case you could address using position rather than the label.  eg using iloc instead.  eg df1.iloc[:,2]... depending on the output of the pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1 = df.pivot('ParamID','EquipmentID','SetValue')
df1['Difference'] = (df1['Line1'].replace(np.nan,0) - df1['Line2'].replace(np.nan,0))
df1
```

[image]

Update with full answer (touch up the table):

```
df1 = df.pivot('ParamID','EquipmentID','SetValue').reset_index()
df1['Difference'] = (df1['Line1'].replace(np.nan,0) - df1['Line2'].replace(np.nan,0))
df1['ParamID'] = np.where((np.isnan(df1.Line1)) | (np.isnan(df1.Line2)), df1['ParamID'].astype(str) + ':---' , df1['ParamID'])
df1.replace(np.nan,0,inplace=True)
df1.columns.name=''
```

[image]

**Answer to updated question**

New Data:

[image]

Step 1:

```
df1 = df.pivot('ParamID','EquipmentID','SetValue').reset_index()
```

[image]

Step 2:

```
df1['Difference'] = (df1.iloc[:,1].replace(np.nan,0) - df1.iloc[:,2].replace(np.nan,0))
df1['ParamID'] = np.where((np.isnan(df1.iloc[:,1])) | (np.isnan(df1.iloc[:,2])), df1['ParamID'].astype(str) + ':---' , df1['ParamID'])
df1.replace(np.nan,0,inplace=True)
df1.columns.name=''
```

[image]

Comment: Additional question. If "Line1" and "Line2" where numbers in the first table. and i change that also in the "Difference"-formula it give a key-error

Comment: @Marvy I've updated the question from the information you have given as best as I can.   If you data is not always Line1 or 2, then you may have to use position instead of label.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) as follows:

```
pivot1 = (df.pivot_table(index='ParamID', 
                         columns='EquipmentID', 
                         values='SetValue', 
                         fill_value=0)
            .reset_index()
            .rename_axis(columns=None)
         )

pivot1['Difference'] = pivot1['Line1'] - pivot1['Line2']
```

Result:

```
print(pivot1)

   ParamID  Line1  Line2  Difference
0        1    217      0         217
1        2      3      3           0
2        4      0      0           0
3        6     17     17           0
```